# Sorting a list of objects, according to their corresponding IDs in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I am attempting to sort a List of objects (A tree structure) using this Dictionary;

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int?>
```

The Tuple contains two IDs, which identify a unique object. The value is the sort order.

The object has a similar structure to

```
public class DmsSortOrder : IRecord
{
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    public int ObjectID { get; set; }

    public int? Order { get; set; }
}
```

I need to sort a

```
List<DmsSortOrder>
```

according to the Dictionary above.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<tagID, objectID>, sortOrder>()
```

I need to sort the list of objects according to the values in the dictionary, but I am unsure how. If it matters, the list is actually a list of lists, but I feel comfortable in using recursion to sort the whole List, once I can sort a single branch.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Would simply using a `SortedDictionary` resolve this?

Comment: @stephen.vakil I don't think so.. Is my original question unclear, or are people scanning over it too quickly?

Comment: You can inherit IComparable in the class with the dictionary and then add you own custom CompareTo() method for sorting.

Comment: I think I get your question now, see my updated answer. But it would be much clearer if you posted an example of you object-containing  data structure, and relevant part of that object definition to show, how the issue is a composite identifier.

Comment: @Gerino I realise that. OP is updated!

Comment: @Rothschild if your value can be derived from the `Tuple` values then you can just use a SortedDictionary with a custom comparer initially.  If not, you could take the current dictionary and create a new SortedDictionary using a custom comparer that looks at the current dictionary still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want a query like this:

```
lists = lists
    .Select(list => list
        .Select(x => new {Key = Tuple.Create(x.TagID, x.ObjectID), DmsSortOrder = x})
        .OrderBy(x => dict.ContainsKey(x.Key) ? dict[x.Key] : int.MaxValue)
        .Select(x => x.DmsSortOrder)
        .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Change the value `int.MaxValue` if you don't want to see the unknown objects at the end.

Comment: I forgot to mention; the dictionary contains sort orders for multiple lists, so I cannot simply sort the dictionary and then select the elements from the List in sorted order. I'm also struggling to read your LINQ query due to inexperience. Does it do this?

Comment: I also get a type inference error on the first select statement. "Try specifying the type arguments explicitly"

Comment: I have screwed up this question. The sort also needs to be in place, as the list contains lists of itself. It is a tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyObject> list; // MyObject has Id1, Id2
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int?> dict;

var sortedObjects = 
    dict.OrderBy(kvp=>kvp.Value))
        .Select(kvp=>
            list.Single(obj =>
                obj.Id1 == kvp.Key.Item1 
                && obj.Id2 == kvp.Key.Item2
            )
        );
```

Comment: I am not attempting to sort the Dictionary. I need to sort a List of objects, where the object's IDs are contained within a Dictionary of ObjectID tuples, and their sort order.

Comment: Here you go - List of MyObject which has two fields that create together a composite primary key, and a dictionary that has a tuple (composite primary key) with sort order as values.

Answer (score 0):

Given these variables:

```
List<UniqueObject> list;
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int?> sortOrders;
```

You should end up with something like this:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(obj => sortOrders[new Tuple(obj.Id1, obj.Id2)]).ToList();
```

I'm sure there a lot of ways to optimize this, but general idea is rather simple.

Comment: You create a lot of unnecessary Tuples! So many wasted bytes, would not use in Apollo-era space rocket ;)

Comment: Yeah, I don't deny it. Don't feel the need to optimize it right away without context. Maybe we're talking about 100 objects? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the list according to the values in the dictionary you can do it doing this:

```
List<DmsSortOrder> list = ...
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int> sortOrder = ...

list.Sort((x, y) => sortOrder[Tuple.Create(x.TagID, x.ObjectID)] - 
                    sortOrder[Tuple.Create(y.TagID, y.ObjectID)]);
//or
list = list.OrderBy(o => sortOrder[Tuple.Create(o.TagID, o.ObjectID)]).ToList();
```